# Laravel detach not working on belongsToMany

Tags: laravel, relation, detach

I have this model: `Company`
Which has a relation: `$this->belongsToMany('App\CallList', 'call_list_companies', 'company_id', 'call_list_id')`

And vice versa: `CallList`
Relation: `$this->belongsToMany('App\Company', 'call_list_companies', 'call_list_id', 'company_id')`

I am able to attach a `Company` to the `CallList`
But I cannot detach a `Company` from a `CallList`

Why is that?

The code I use for detaching the Company:
`$company->call_lists()->detach($call_list);`

I also tried the other way:
`$call_list->companies()->detach($company);`

It just returns null when I do it.
I checked that the both the company and the call list exists and that there was a relation between the two in the database.

Anyone have a clue what I am doing wrong?
I do not get any errors or anything either.

If it's worth mentioning, I am also using a pivot table for the relations.

Comment: Try only with $call_list->companies()->detach()

Comment: That works, but it detaches every company from the call list, and I only want to remove the selected one. I checked the ID's in the pivot table to check that the relation is correct, and it is. I did `dd()` on the company and call list vars to check the ID's there too, and that is also correct. It just doesn't want to detach a single relation.

Comment: $call_list->companies()->detach($request->id)....... Can you try that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filter the relationship query down to just the call list with matching ID and then call `detach()`.

Try:

```php
$company->call_lists()->where('id', $call_list->id)->detach();
```

Comment: Okay, so this worked. I don't know why I can't do it the other way i tried.

Comment: It deletes all relations.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar or the same problem and faced it twice during last 2 years.

I figured out that the relation used soft deletion and it made this problem.

My relation `belongsToMany` used `Pivot` class.

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class EntityUser extends Pivot
{
   use SoftDeletes; // it makes the problem

   // some code
}
```

The table had column `deleted_at`. But the problem was made `SoftDeletes` class.

When I run `$user->entities()->detach($entity)` it returned `1` that means one record was touched or removed, but the table and real results had no changes.

I removed `SoftDeletes` and it had worked. I also removed that column from the table.

### Solution

- Remove `SoftDeletes` from the pivot class. Laravel doesn't have official support of it. https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/2750
- Remove `deleted_at` from the pivot table. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#available-command-aliases

Comment: old issue, but for me a current problem. This solution kind-of worked. I don't think I have softdeletes unless laravel has changed that behaviour as a default. I found the term SoftDeletes only in the vendor directory. I did however add a transaction - commit around the detach(), and that solved my problem.