# How to use detach function in laravel with mongodb?

Tags: laravel, mongodb, mongoose

I am using laravel and mongodb but i didn't find any function to detach many to many relationship data. Code below for many to many relationship data with related_ids in both collections.

```
public function Teams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            'App\Team', null, 'team_ids', 'user_ids'
        );
    }
```

Comment: Instead of `belongsToMany`, try to use `embedsMany` relationship and then try to use `detach` method. Reference [EmbedsMany.php](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/blob/09fcda8d21edfeb49416893bf916e13647d79f4b/src/Jenssegers/Mongodb/Relations/EmbedsMany.php#L207)

Comment: in embedsMany we have to push objects so documents takes a lot of space

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58686144/9636400